# Line Chart showing count (or sum) instead of values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I just started with Power BI. I'm trying to plot a line chart with dates on the X-axis and the corresponding values of a EURUSD rates series.

What I did step by step is:

1. Imported a datasheet from excel with several series of FX rates (EURUSD, EURGBP, etc.)
2. Selected "Don't summarize" in Summarization for the series EURUSD.
3. Create a line chart, where I dragged & dropped "Dates" into the "Axis" field and my EURUSD series into the "Values" field.

But automatically, Power BI shows it as "Count of" instead of the values (It shows me I have more or less 260 values from 2018 till 2021 and fewer values for 2022).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering.

I found the issue. It was in the dates. It was by default selected as "Date hierarchy" instead of "Date"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the EURUSD field was imported as a **text** field.
You should change the data type for these fields **to numeric**:

bookmark "data" -> tab "column tools" -> setting "data type" -> select the desired type, for example, "decimal number"

P.S. I'm not using English in PowerBI, so the names of the settings may not be accurate